# intersection_update for dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, intersection

I want a dictionary class that implements an `intersection_update` method, similar in spirit to `dict.update` but restricting the updates only to those keys that are already present in the calling instance (see below for some example implementations).

But, in the spirit of Wheel Reinvention Avoidance, before I go off implementing (and writing tests for, etc.) a mapping class with this additional functionality, does anything like this already exist in a more-or-less standard module?

---

To be clear, the `intersection_update` method I have in mind would do something like this:

```
def intersection_update(self, other):
    for k in self.viewkeys() & other.viewkeys():
        self[k] = other[k]
```

...although an actual implementation may attempt some possible optimizations, like, e.g.:

```
def intersection_update(self, other):
    x, y = (self, other) if len(self) < len(other) else (other, self)
    for k in x.iterkeys():
        if k in y:
            self[k] = other[k]
```

Edit: In the original version of this post I had written "Alternatively, is there a standard Python idiom that obviates the need to implement a [class with a `intersection_update`] method?", but I deleted almost immediately it because, upon further reflection, I realized that was an invitation for weak answers, since I know enough of the "core" of the Python language to be pretty certain that no such idiom exists, at least not one that would match the advantages (generality, legibility, ease of typing) of a dedicated method.

Comment: Based on your edit, I guess you're aware of `d1.update((k, v) for k, v in d2 if k in d1)`. Personally, I think the above is quite readable -- in fact, I'd say it's more obvious what the above does than `d1.intersection_update(d2)` at first glance. If I saw `d1.intersection_update(d2)`, I'd have to go look at the documentation to be sure.

Comment: @senderle: Yes, but when I first saw `set.intersection_update` I also had to look at the docs.  The point is that, once one knows what `d1.intersection_update(d2)` does, then reading it is immediate, whereas when one comes across something like `d1.update((k, v) for k, v in d2 if k in d1)` in source code, one always has to parse the expression part-by-part to be able to determine what it does.  Granted, any increase in legibility that one may get from a separate method is too slight, by itself, to warrant having it.  It's the other benefits of a dedicated method that tip the decision for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def dict_intersection(d1, d2):
    return dict((key, d2[key] or d1[key]) for key in frozenset(d1) & frozenset(d2))
```

Or, for python versions >= 2.7:

```
def dict_intersection(d1, d2):
    return {key: d2[key] or d1[key] for key in d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys()}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `frozenset` instead of `set`? Also, in 2.7, the object returned by `dict.viewkeys` is set-like, and supports `&` and `|` operations natively.

Comment: You right, in >= 2.7 you can use `d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an pseudo code which you may use with existing update function, but any ways if you want to extend dictionary then your piece of code is also valid - but that would add some extra headache of using your class of dict everywhere.

```
In [1]: x = dict(name='abc', age=23)

In [2]: y = dict(name='xyz', notes='Note 123', section=None)

In [3]: #x.update(dict((k,y[k]) for k in y if k in x))

In [3]: x.update((k,v) for k,v in y.iteritems() if k in x)

In [4]: x
Out[4]: {'age': 23, 'name': 'xyz'}
```

EDIT: updated the code as per kjo's comments using iteritems method

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with that idiom.  I prefer this variant: `x.update((k, v) for k, v in y.iteritems() if k in x)`.  (Note that it does not create an intermediate `dict`).  BTW, immediately after I posted the question, I deleted the line asking for idioms that may serve the same purpose as an `intersection_update` method, but it looks from your answer like I was not quick enough.  Sorry about that.